# xpath expression to simulate subquery with multiple creiteria

Tags: debugging, xpath, subquery, predicate, xpath-1.0

I have to find a value in an xml using two criteria on two differents nodest using xpath 1.0

I'try to explain with an example: If we have the following xml

```
<root>
<obj>
    <index>5</index>
    <datalist>
        <data>
            <code>X</code>
            <value>AAA</value>
        </data>
        <data>
            <code>Y</code>
            <value>BBB</value>
        </data>
    </datalist>
</obj>
<obj>
    <index>3</index>
    <datalist>
        <data>
            <code>Z</code>
            <value>CCC</value>
        </data>
    </datalist>
</obj>
<obj>
    <index>4</index>
    <datalist>
        <data>
            <code>X</code>
            <value>DDD</value>
        </data>
    </datalist>
</obj>
<obj>
    <index>2</index>
    <datalist>
        <data>
            <code>Y</code>
            <value>EEE</value>
        </data>
    </datalist>
</obj>
```

we would like to retrive the `<value>` of the `<obj/data>` with `<code=X>` within the `<obj>` with minimum `<index>` (in our exaple we woult have DDD as result).

I have tried the following expression but it seams to not work:

```
/root/obj[datalist/data/code='X'][not(preceding-sibling::obj/index <= index)
and not(following-sibling::obj/index <= index)]/datalist/data/value
```

but it does not work

Comment: please rephrase your question or check the syntax, 
seems some stuff is missing...

Comment: How can "DDD" be the wanted result when its `obj/index` is 4 and at the sme time there is an `obj/index =2` ? This contradiction makes the question meaningless. Please, edit and correct.

Comment: You are right, I have fixed the example indicating that I'm finding the minimum obj/index but with obj/datalist/data/code = X

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After quite a while of staring at this I think I've figured out what's up. In short, you're enforcing `code='X'` in the initial match for `obj`, but not in the sibling axes.

In other words, you're saying: "Find me a `obj` node which a) has no siblings with a lower `index`, and b) has the descendant `code='X'`. No nodes meet these criteria.

Of course you meant to consider only siblings that *also* had the descendant `code='X'`, not just any *sibling*.

Try this (runnable at [this XML Playground](http://www.xmlplayground.com/FCbbdA))

```
root/obj[datalist/data/code='X'][
    not(preceding-sibling::obj[
        datalist/data/code='X'
    ]/index &lt; index)
    and
    not(following-sibling::obj[
        datalist/data/code='X'
    ]/index &lt; index)
]/datalist/data/value
```

Comment: You have reached the point! Your xpath is very near to the solution. I have only lightly modified your expression this way: "/root/obj[datalist/data/code='X'][
not(preceding-sibling::obj[
  datalist/data/code='X'
]/index &lt; index)
and
not(following-sibling::obj[
  datalist/data/code='X'
]/index &lt; index)
]/datalist/data[code='X']/value" and now it seems to work for me. thank you so much